# Best pattern to avoid module globals from being cleaned up

Tags: python, reference-counting

I'm finding that some modules that defined global objects are re-created when the module is import later:

```
# mymodule
pool = MyPoolObject()
```

and if accessed from some code:

```
def f():
   from mymodule import pool
   print id(pool)
```

Subsequent calls to f print different ids! This is surprising. I expect that when f exits, its the last reference to mymodule and the global is unloaded. I can't for a reference to mymodule in the caller of f, because, ultimately its an RPC service that doesn't know what modules it will be calling (it receives pickled objects and calls them).

Is there a good way to avoid this behavior and keep the globals from being unloaded? One quick workaround is to add a reference in sys:

```
# mymodule
import sys
sys._mymodule_pool = MyPoolObject()
pool = sys._mymodule_pool
```

... but even this doesn't seem like it wouldn't guarantee that its not unloaded.

Comment: First of all, importing modules inside a function is code smell...

Comment: As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said, why would you even need to import a module inside of a function? All imports should be done once at the top of the file.

Comment: Are you doing this because it might make things... faster?

Comment: I have called f() in python2.x and python3.x, in every case same ID

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've written it this way because that is when happens when an unpickled function is called by an RPC API - there's no guarantee that the referenced modules are already imported.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Depend what part. If you mean pre-allocating the pool -- yes. This is a 1000x speedup since it maintains network connections and cached results. But the RPC method I'm using (unpickling a function) is somewhat slower than other options. However, it lets me creater a cluster of very simple workers, and execute whatever code I want on them with very fewer constraints.

Comment: I don't see how the ID would be different each time you call `f()`. I just tried and it's not the case. The `mymodule` module has a reference on the `pool` object, and the module, under normal conditions, does not get unloaded/reloaded for the interpreter's lifetime. How are you calling `f()` multiple times?